# Let X be the unit interval [0, 1]. Find a function $f: X \rightarrow X$ that is a symmetric relation on X.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

"R is symmetric if and only if xRy $\Rightarrow$ yRx"

> Question: Let X be the unit interval [0, 1]. Find a function $f: X \rightarrow X$ that is a symmetric relation on X.
>   Source: Set Theory, You-Feng Lin"

My answer f:[0, 1] $\Rightarrow$ [0, 1], f(x)=x

The answer is a function reflexive on X, but it's also symmetric. Is this answer correct? Can you give other answers for the question?

Comment: $f(x)=1-x$? Does $f$ have to be continuous?

Comment: @bof [0, 1] means {x∈R|0≤x≤1}. Other conditions are not given.

Comment: Other continuous possibilities include $x\mapsto\sqrt{1-x^2}$ or $x\mapsto\dfrac{1-x}{1+3x}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try $f(x)=1-x$ or any other [*involutory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics)) map.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your answer is correct. A similar answer may also be created by putting
$f(x)=x$ if $x\neq 1/3$ or $x\neq 1/4$ , while $f(1/4)=1/3$ and $f(1/3)=1/4$. Or in a similar way create a map such that $f(f(x))=x$.

Answer (score 0):

Given a function $f: X \rightarrow Y$, define the relation corresponding to $f$ as the subset $R:=\{(x,f(x)): x \in X\}$ of $X \times Y$.  The relation is symmetric if $(x,y) \in R$ implies $(y,x) \in R$.  So, whenever $(x,f(x)) \in R$, we want $(f(x),x) \in R$.  But to say $(f(x),x) \in R$ is to say that $f(f(x)) = x$ (because, by definition of $R$, $(a,b) \in R$ iff $f$ of the first coordinate is equal to the second coordinate).  You can find many functions which satisfy the equation $f(f(x))=x$ on the given domain. $f(x)=x$ is one of them.